# Type is still str, not float

Tags: python, function, types

Not turning into float:

```
def floaty(s):
try:
    k = 0
    for elem in s:
        if 0 <= float(elem) <= 1:
            k += 1
    if k == len(s):
        for elem in s:
            elem = float(elem)
        return s
    else:
        return None
except ValueError:
    return None
```

type of elements of the list [0.1, 0.2] is still str, not float

```
    for elem in s:
        elem = float(elem)
    return s
```

why doesn't this work?

Comment: Because reassigning `elem` does not affect your list. Python variables don't work that way. Use `s = [float(elem) for elem in s]`.

Comment: The function has `return s`, which is the same value that was passed in.  So of course it is still a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
  for elem in s:
        elem = float(elem)
```

do:

```
s = [float(x) for x in s]
```

Which is list comprehension, and will make a new list of `float` versions for every element in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Python does not support this kind of variable redefinition. So, you can't redefine a variable that you're using in the loop, in this case that is `elem`. I suggest creating another list and returning it, instead of returning the old one.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer